# python WooCommerce REST API How to retrieve parent id of product using the variation id?

Tags: python, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

using [woocommerce api](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/), I need to find a way for retrieving the parent id of the product using the variation id.
at woocommerce if a product has a color or size variation a new id is generated for it under the parent id, I have no problems about getting information of the parent id and knowing all product variations it contains by :

```
# product id: 1394511 
print(wcapi.get("products/1394511").json())
```

I can also get the information of a variation id but only if I have the parent id as :

```
# variation id : 1394538 , parent id : 1394511
print(wcapi.get("products/1394511/variations/1394538").json())
```

but at the docs, I find no way to get the parent id by only having the variation id, any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: The clue is right there in your URL: `products/**1394511**/variations/1394538`